# How to scroll RecycleView in transition?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I have change my fragments with `Transitions` (exit/enter-Transition). First fragment contains `RecycleView` and when `Slide` transition will execute I have problem - my last `View` in `RecycleView` cropped.

[image]

I have try to fix it and scroll `RecycleView` to end of the list when transition animation started, but it doesn't work.

I try use `ChangeScroll` but it doesn't help me.

[image]

**P.S.** Add code and xml:

Xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rvList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

And code of creating exit transition:

```
fun getSelectDestinationPlaceTransitionSetExit() =
        TransitionSet().apply {
            addTransition(Slide(Gravity.START).addTarget(R.id.rvList))

            ordering = TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER
            duration = AnimationConfig.CHANGE_SCREEN_TRANSITIONS_DURATION
        }
```

Comment: show your xml file

Comment: post a gif to demonstrate better ...!! "my last View in RecycleView cropped." difficult to understand horizontal recyclerView can stay cropped..!!

Comment: @SantanuSur added

Comment: cool got it :) use a **handler with postDelayed** and **onButtonClick** firstScroll the recyclerView to the **end** and **start the slide animation inside the delayed handler** ..it can be done by this way i dont code in kotlin ..you will know it better.. !!

Comment: basically delay the transition for say (300 ms) and scroll the recyclerView before it !! you start the scroll and the handler together.. ( **but the transition will be 300 ms later** )

Comment: The Idea of scroll to last Position ist realy good. would recommend to change also the layout width of the RecyclerView to Wrap Content on Transition. then it should all be visible

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your recyclerview with this code.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/simpleList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/height_of_app_bar"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

hope this will work for you.